# Is There Any Overhead Difference Between Protobuf Runtime and Static Tag Methods?

Tags: performance, tags, runtime, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

We are using Probuf on a .netcf target.  Everything works well.  I started out using the static [ProtoContract], [ProtoMember, 1].. etc.  My colleage was concerned about adding potential overhead to the class object so I switched to a runtime model with .add(# , " ") which seemed more "disconnected" from the class in question.  I actually prefer the static tags in the class since names are inherently updated if variable names are refactored later.  Since I do not know how or what protobuf does under the hood, is there any advantage or disadvantage to using the static tags vs. the runtime model in terms of overhead, speed, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Anyway, http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.com/2011/07/comparing-protobuf-net-serialisation.html contains a little reply from Marc Gravell, the Protobuf.NET author: "Your code [with the RuntimeTypeModel] just shows another way to *configure* it. It *should perform the same* either way unless you have explicitly turned off automatic compilation."

Comment: We pass classes around a lot in the project and didn't know if things got passed along when tagging the variables within the class.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @user2864740 on this occasion, especially targeting cf, there is more that can be said...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't profiled this aspect extensively - mainly because any overhead from reflection *on the attributes* is done once and once only. There might be a slight difference  in cold-start performance, but: if the ultimate in startup performance is your aim you should ideally try to use the precompiler available in the google-code download. This **only** works with the attribute model  but has the advantage that when using a precompiled model no reflection **whatsoever** occurs at runtime. It will also generate pure IL, where-as CF is usually very restricted so IIRC the runtime usage is forced to use some reflection even for things like member access. Finally, it means you can use the "CoreOnly" rather than "Full" build, which is smaller and less complex.

http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/introducing-protobuf-net-precompiler.html

Comment: If a class is tagged upfront (non-runtime), is there any additional items within the class object itself that would be passed along with the class during normal (non-protobuf) usage.

Comment: @user2824070 no; the metadata is basically inert unless code is actively looking at attributes via reflection. It certainly has no per-instance cost, for example